# Drop-down list for edit summary on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, editing

I usually edit posts for grammatical and spelling errors and strongly believe that most edits are for the same reason. I do hate typing "fixed grammar", or "improved formatting". So, why wouldn't Stack Exchange add a drop down list for this purpose. The list can contain the common purpose of edits, and miscellaneous issues can be typed as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use your browser's autocomplete feature. I use it on Firefox, macOS, and I know it works for Safari too:

[image]

For some browsers, it seems to work [out of the box](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-whether-firefox-automatically-fills-forms), in other ones you might need to enable it explicitly.

Also, once you reach 2k reputation you don't need to type an edit summary anymore; the system will [automatically generate one for you](https://meta.superuser.com/revisions/14063/3). Edit summaries can be very useful but grammar corrections and fixed typos are usually quite obvious.

Comment: This will surely work. I didn't know that we don't need to type edit summaries after 2k. Thanks.